# Jenkins multibranch scan branch and start all build job when Jenkins-master restart

Tags: jenkins, multibranch-pipeline

I have too many multibranch tasks, and every task has many branches. Hundreds of build jobs were triggered when Jenkins restart. One of the scan log is as follows

```
Checking branch release-13.6.2
Met criteria
Takeover for multibranch-job-xxxx » release-13.6 by source #1 from source that no longer exists
Branch reopened: release-13.6 (e7484fcf80dd6780161c0155fbc68aaddc20b76b)
Scheduled build for branch: release-13.6
```

I don't want those build, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `id = some_unique_name` in your job DSL.
For example

```
multibranchPipelineJob('job-dsl-plugin_multibranch') {
  branchSources {
    git {
      id = some_unique_name
      remote('https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin.git')
    }
  }
}
```

Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-43693

Let me know how it works for you